# Java Applet / Javascript - How to manipulate print setup when printing a pdf through web?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, applet, web

How is it possible to control or manipulate the page setup in a web browser - im printing from a pdf file (adobe reader plugin). Is there a way, say for example changing the printer or setting the page size without the user intervention?

Is it possible through the use of Java Applet or Javascript? or any other java web based library?

Answer (score 0):

Not through JavaScript, at least not cross-browser--printing uses the browser's native print capabilities. You might be able to play some games with an Applet and Java's printing functionality.

Comment: Thank for your response Dave! How is it possible to control or manipulate the page setup in a web browser - im printing from a pdf file (adobe reader plugin). Is there a way, say for example changing the printer or setting the page size without the user intervention?

Comment: No--and it's a good thing, because it's my printer, not the web app's.

Comment: I'm creating an intranet web based application in java. I heard something about java applet capability for printing but I don't have a concrete example. So, it is not possible to control the page setup when printing a PDF file (adobe reader plugin)?

Comment: @Adan I don't see how; that'd be using the native print capabilities of the plugin. Things like [this](http://bfo.com/blog/2009/09/28/silently_print_a_pdf_from_a_web_browser.html) might bring you closer to what you want--dunno.

Comment: A Java applet would have some limited capabilities to control the page, but probably no more than the PDF & Adobe Reader has. Meaning you can control the page size and orientation, but the system will still control which printer is selected, the output tray, etc. Also, I would only expect a signed and trusted applet to have these capabilities. In short, an applet would be quite a few hoops to jump through, and I don't think you'd gain anything.